# Getting the contents of each bootstrap tab and printing them in separate divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I would like to do is get the contents of each bootstrap tab and print them in different divs. Basically, I would like to trigger the el.tab('show') function for each [data-toggle='tab'], grab the shown contents, and print them in different divs on the same page.

```js
$(function() {
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
});
```

```css
.new
{
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">This is Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">This is Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">This is Messages</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">This is Settings</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="newHome" class='new'>
    Want to print home content here
  </div>
  <div id="newProfile" class='new'>
    Want to print profile content here
  </div>
    <div id="newMessages" class='new'>
    Want to print messages content here
  </div>
    <div id="Settings" class='new'>
    Want to print settings content here
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/zixihexepu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>` from your html head as jQuery is already defined, defining multiple times will cause problem.

Then try this:

```
$(function() {
  //This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown.
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    //get the content href
    var contentId = $(e.target).attr('href');
    //from content href prepare new div id and show content html there
    $("#new" + contentId.substring(1).capitalizeFirstLetter()).html($("" + contentId).html());
  })
});

String.prototype.capitalizeFirstLetter = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bymv5spj/)

bootstrap tab event [Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events)